# How can I use %s to replace text within a file in python?

Tags: python, string, file, substitution, format-string

I've been working on a project where I open and read a file and replace its text with input, this is what I have been trying to do to put certain words in,

```
for i in range(0, length):
    finallib = str(picks[choice]) % (picked[i])
```

where length is the length - 1 of the list 'picked' and picked is a list of words. 'picks[choice]' is the selection of text from the file that the user chooses to put new words into. Within the file, The text goes like this 'file text file text file text %s file text file text file text', and I get the error that there are not enough arguments for format string. How can I get it to replace what I want it to?

P.S. the substitution doesn't go into another file or the same file, it is put into a variable that is displayed after it is calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `format()`?

```
for i in range(length): # range automatically starts at 0
    finallib = '{} % {}'.format(picks[choice],picked[i])
```

Or cleaner (list comprehension):

```
finallib = ['{} % {}'.format(picks[choice],picked[i]) for i in range(length)]
```

Comment: so I tried that exact phrasing and it returned the file choice without substitutions included, right now the spots reserved for inputs are marked with '%s', should they be marked with something else or is the code missing that piece somewhere? When I tried the second option it printed the file selection multiple times.

Comment: `'{ }".format(x)` places the variable `x` in the `{ }` inside the string (formed by the quotes). If you have many variables just use `{ }` where ever they need to go. In the above example there are 2 variables and each is placed around the `%` symbol in the string at the order they are written in the `format()`. But what you said should also work - namely, using `%s`. Without seeing the rest of the code there is not much I can suggest.

Comment: so I tried to replace %s with {} and I tried to just use %s where you had {} in the example, when using the first method output was only '%s % %s' and when I tried the second it output the file selection followed by % {}. I do not understand this premise very well

Comment: Read about `format()` online: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/

Comment: I have read the article, and I now don't think its the command screwing it but the way it gets where it's going. the way I get the string is by access from a file, and I think that that is screwing up the way that it reads either %s or {}. The error I am now getting is 'tuple range out of index' or something like that, and from what I know thats what happens when there aren't enough arguments. I know I have the right amount of arguments but can't get it to replace each sub with an element in the list. I believe it wants to replace the first sub with the entire list. how do I overcome this?

Comment: Please edit your question so that all the information is provided. I am not sure I understand your question to be honest.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so please consider upvoting and accepting (checkmark) it.

Comment: not really, I ended up using a separate command that seems somewhat overcomplex, but I could not get anything you offered to me to work in my benefit. I sincerely appreciate the help though! :)